# How to filter using one text view content in multiple text view SimpleAdapter with EditText Android

Tags: android

I have SimpleAdapter with multiple text views, it is filtering well. But it is filter all text views in the list, but i want to filter only KEY_NAME (R.id.name) feild only.

Because if name and registration contain same word, it is coming twice. So i want to filter only name feild.

How can i do it ? Please guide me. Thank You

```
 // Adding menuItems to ListView
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems, R.layout.list_item,
        new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_NAME,KEY_REG, KEY_SIM, KEY_GNAME,KEY_LUPDATE }, new int[] {
                R.id.deviceid1, R.id.name, R.id.registration1,      R.id.simno, R.id.gname, R.id.duration });

setListAdapter(adapter);

/**
 * Enabling Search Filter
 * */
// Search Feild

inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // When user changed the Text
        ((SimpleAdapter)VehicleList.this.adapter).getFilter().filter(cs);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                  int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32592862/filter-multiple-row-simpleadapter-with-edittext-android)

Comment: hi, the same one i have added yesterday, but no one has answered ...